# R shiny app to pdf with Rmarkdown, how to well display data tables in pdf

Tags: r, shiny, r-markdown

I have a R shiny app where I have many tables. I would like to be able to download a pdf report from this app. In this report, I would like to display the tables used in the app. I have already managed to well display the tables in a html report by using DT::datatable, but now i would like to do it in a pdf. The issue that I have is that the tables are cut on the right and I don't know how to display them entirely and well on the page. I have searched a lot but couldn't find something that work. Here is I hope a good reproductible example.

For this example I have used the csv file [organizations-100.csv](https://github.com/datablist/sample-csv-files/raw/main/files/organizations/organizations-100.csv).

Shiny App (the reactive is not useful but I tried to replicate a little my app. In my app, I have tables where I select lines depending on the user's input. I have a reactive list of tables, and then in the Rmarkdown, I go through the list and display the tables).

```
library(utils)
library(tools)
library(readxl)
library(shiny)

table1 <- read.csv("organizations-100.csv", sep = ",")

ui <- fluidPage(

    # Application title
    titlePanel("Test"),

    downloadButton("report_pdf", "Download a PDF")

)


server <- function(input, output) {

  table <- reactive ({
    data.frame(table1)
  })

  output$report_pdf <- downloadHandler(
    filename = "Test.pdf",
    content = function(file) {
  
    params <- list(table0 = table())
  
    rmarkdown::render(input = 'Test.Rmd',
                    output_file = 'Test.pdf',
                    params = params,
                    envir = new.env())
    })
}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Rmarkdown

````
  ---
 title: "Test"
 output: pdf_document
 params:
 table0: NA
 header-includes:
  - \usepackage{tabu}
 ---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = FALSE)
```

```{r,echo=FALSE}
library(knitr)
library(kableExtra)
library(gt)
```

```{r, echo=FALSE,results = 'asis'}
 # With kable
  # Doesn't display well

params$table0 %>%
 kable() %>%
 kable_styling(full_width = T)

```

```{r, echo=FALSE,results = 'asis'}
# With gt
# Doesn't display well
pivot_table_gt <- params$table0 %>%
gt() %>%
 tab_header("Hello")

pivot_table_gt
```
````

In this example, I would say that kable works better than with my shiny App where it is really cut on the right. With gt, it looks the same as in my app.

Answer (score 0):

There is no good way to export any tables to PDF without manual inspection and get a good result (e.g. without cut on the right) because PDF reproduce paper pages that have a limited size.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Wouldn't it be possible to reduce the margins of the pdf page then ? By doing so, most of my tables could have enough space.

Comment: Ultimately, I download my html report where the data tables are well displayed and then save it as a pdf.